# Moxi unable to change number of client connection limit

Tags: memcached, couchbase, moxiemanager

I am trying to control the number of client connections(upstream connections) to Moxi. By default the value is 1024. 
The documentation specifies changing this value using the -c commandline parameter.
I restarted Moxi in the following way:

> /etc/init.d/moxi-server start -c 10

Even after this, I do not seem the changes being reflected. I am able to create more than 10 connections.
There is no option even in the moxi.cfg file to change this.
I am verifying the change using parameter in Moxi stats:

> memcached:settings:maxconns

- Is there another way to change this parameter?
- Why isn't the change being applied?
- Is maxconns the right way to validate it?

Moxi version used: 1.8 and 2.5

Any help appreciated !